# Update null field from same field if not null

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mariadb

I want to update all NULL PlayerId field with existing PlayerId matching the exact same Name into the same table

I have for the same Name some NULL PlayerID and some with the good value :

```
    SELECT count(*) as c, Name, PlayerId FROM my_table 
    WHERE Name = 'John,Doh' GROUP BY PlayerId order by c ASC;


+---+-----------+-------------+
| c | Name      | PlayerId    |
+---+-----------+-------------+
| 2 | John,Doh  |        NULL |
| 8 | John,Doh  |     2900084 |
+---+-----------+-------------+
```

I don't know if its possible from the same table or should I create a temporary one ?

Thanks,

Comment: What happens when you have 2 players with the same name?

Comment: The Name used to be the primary key but now an id has appear so I need to propagate it first, then, I will use Id to match player...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update your_table t1
join your_table t2 on t1.name = t2.name
                  and t2.playerId is not null
set t1.playerId = t2.playerId
where t1.playerId is null
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine before the edit but it was quite slow Query OK, 59 rows affected (5 min 56.45 sec) Rows matched: 1110  Changed: 59  do you think it will be fastest after your edit (Im gonna try but need to reset the DB first )?

Comment: If you have performance problems then look at the indexes defined in your table and optimize them.